# Used WWW:Mechanize to login and download a file in perl script but cannot get into the actual page content

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to login to the site using Mechanize in Perl script. It does log into the index page but I try to get the content of the page where file hyperlinks are present then I am not logged in I assume that after looking at the content of the page

Secondly, How can we download a file from the indirect hyperlink of a file which directs to some action which then downloads a file. Please guide, as there is not much help available for this particular use case

Below is my code

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP;

my $username = 'user'; 
my $password = 'pass';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech -> cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech -> get('some_website/index.html?#');
$mech -> form_name('form');
$mech -> field ('user' => $username);
$mech -> field ('password' => $password);
$mech->submit();
$mech -> get('actual_page_address_with_file_hyperlinks?adfgenDispatchAction=examine&idProgressivo=0&idFlusso=4200212');
#print $mech-> content();

$mech->save_content("result.html");

my @links = $mech->links();
for my $link ( @links ) {

    #if(index($link->text,"Scarica")!= -1)
    #{
    printf "%s, %s\n", $link->text, $link->url;
    #}
}
```

;

Comment: It looks like you are having two problems. You need to find the path in the HTML, and then you need to download that. Let's start with the first one. Does logging in work and do you get the page after having logged in?

Comment: Also note you are loading a lot of modules that you don't use. Since you already load WWW::Mechanize, it is probably easiest to use that instead of plain LWP::UserAgent. Mech is an extension (subclass) of LWP::UA and can do everything and more. You don't need to load `LWP` or `LWP::Simple` as you don't use them. You also don't need `curl`, as that is a completely different library that does the sames things in a different way.

Comment: I do log in to the first page i.e. the index html page, after that when I try to get the content of the page where hyperlinks of files are present. It again logs out

Comment: I have used mechanize also, i get logged into the index page and get all the hyperlink, but when i try to get the hyperlinks of the desired page it does not allow me

Comment: Updated the code and description, please help

Comment: Mechanize do not support JavaScript. And the page is submitting form using JavaScript, could this be reason its not working?

Comment: http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#JavaScript – try `WWW::Scripter` or `WWW::Mechanize::Chrome` or `WWW::Selenium`

Comment: It's JWT based authentication, that's why it cannot log in without token. Need to add the token in the cookies first.

Comment: I used WWW:: Selenium and I was able to log in to the site and download the files. Issue resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the website was using CSRF token and there was no hidden tag defined in the login page to store CSRF token, so token generation in the script was not helping.

I used WWW:: Selenium and I was able to log in to the site and download the files. Issue resolved –